# CMake Set the Test Directory

Tags: cmake

I am using CTest. I have all my tests in a folder

```
target
src
test
  |- featureA.c
  |- featureB.c
```

It's quite annoying that the tests are generated in a target folder within that test folder, I would rather all my tests get added to the global `target` folder.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your folder as an option to [add_test](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_test.html) command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).